# jquery hover on mouseover my subcategories disappear

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover

MY jQuery CODE:

```
$(function()
{
    $(".third-categories").hide();  
});

$(function()
{
    $(".second-categories").hover(function() {
    $(this).next(".third-categories").show("slow");},
    function(){
    $(this).next(".third-categories").hide("slow");}
    );

});
$(function()
{
    $(".third-categories").mouseover(function(){(".third-categories").show("slow");});  
});
```

MY HTML CODE:
I m writting on smarty template but the outfit looks like this:

```
<ul class="second-categories">
<ul class="second-categories">
<ul class="third-categories" style="display: none;">
  <li style="padding-left: 13px;">
</ul>
<ul class="second-categories">
<ul class="second-categories">
<ul class="third-categories" style="display: none;">
  <li style="padding-left: 13px;">
  <li style="padding-left: 13px;">
</ul>
<ul class="second-categories">
</html>
```

When i mouseover the "second-category" ul i want the "third-categories" ul to appear.and this is happening but also I want the "third-categories" ul to stay visible when i have my mouse over it. I tried everything and i don t know what s the problem... if anybody could help would be appreciated... thanks!

Comment: Done! sorry for the trouble... anyway, i used the :hover class and not jquery.In case anybody interested:

Comment: ul.second-categories:hover + ul.third-categories{display:block;}
ul.third-categories:hover{display:block;}

Comment: why don't you nest your `ul`s

Comment: You'll either have to put "third-categories" inside "second-categories" in your HTML, or do some javascript magic with setting and clearing timeouts on mouseenter and mouseleave on the two elements.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for: **Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/8gdxG/

Also your HTML looks bit wrong. ALso please note you don't need to add document ready multiple times once is suffice the need.

Rest code below will help the cause `:)`

**JQ Code**

```
$('.second-categories').mouseleave(function() {

        $(this).find('li ul.third-categories').each(function () {
            $(this).stop().slideUp('slow');
        });
    });

    $("ul li").mouseenter(function() { $(this).children('ul').stop().slideDown('slow'); });​
```

**HTML Code**

```
<ul class="second-categories">
    <li>Hulk
      <ul class="third-categories">
          <li>child1</li>
         <li>child2</li>
      </ul>
     </li>    
    <li>Ironman
     <ul class="third-categories">
          <li>child</li>
         <li>child</li>
      </ul> 
    </li>
    <li>Thor
      <ul class="third-categories">
          <li>child</li>
      </ul>              
    </li>
</ul>​
```

Comment: I ve been gone for a while,thank you for your time! Tats_innit i made some changes and i think your solution is excactly what i was looking for. thanks again!